# How to run "delayed_jobs" on DigitalOcean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, delayed-job, digital-ocean

I've tried to find some tutorials/sources that could help me with that, but I was not very successful.
Currently, when I run a method with a `.delay` functionality, the record is saved to the `delayed_jobs` database table, but it's not executed.

Any tips to make this functionality work on DigitalOcean server (Ubuntu, nginx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start a job runner. Refer to the section RUNNING JOBS in the documentation.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

The basic command is

`RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start`